# Generate face mask for any person

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

How can I generate face mask for any face dimension using opencv 2.4.2 and C++?

This code here specifies some values for the left and front ROI face areas for a specific person:

```
Mat left=imread("left.jpg");
Mat front=imread("front.jpg");
int x=30, y=10, w=240, h=200, offset_x=20, offset_y=6;
Mat leftROI=left(Rect(x,y,w,h));
Mat frontROI=front(Rect(x-offset_x,y+offset_y,w,h)); 

//create mask
Mat gray1,thr1;
cvtColor(leftROI,gray1,CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold( gray1, thr1,190, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV );
Mat gray2,thr2;
cvtColor(frontROI,gray2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold( gray2, thr2,190, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV );
```

but every face is not the same. How can face mask be generated for any one?

Comment: The good old pie-in-the-face instant face mask works with just about any face dimension :))

Comment: pie-in-the-face?sorry I did not understand

Comment: First of all, setting "hard-coded" thresholds will not work. You need to find a mathematical representation of the face colors that is automatic. Once you do that, you will be able to create your face mask with ease.